# Circle layout with custom center coordinates

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm building a dynamic graph with cytoscape.js over a world map generated with jVectorMap.
Starting with coordinates in LAT / LON format from json data, I can convert them in point.x / point.y over the generated map with:

```
var nodePoint = theMap.latLngToPoint(node.data.lat, node.data.lon)
```

and then I can add the new node in the graph with:

```
cy.add({
        group: "nodes",
        position: { x: nodePoint.x, y: nodePoint.y },
        style: {
        'background-color': node.color
        },   
        data: {
            id: node.id,
            name: node.label,
            customData: node.data,
        }
    })
```

This part works, but when json returns multiple nodes with the same coordinates, I would like to spread these nodes around the point with the common LAT / LON information.

I'm able to identify these nodes and apply a dedicated layout to them, but the resulting layount is located in the center of the screen / div of graph.

What I want to know is if there is a simple way to apply a Circle Layout with specific center point.

(I would like to avoid implementing the solution that I'm evaluating... i.e to build a bounding box around the center point and see what happens, (with the bounding box size that grows along with node number in the same point))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Wine and cheese example included in the documentation they use the bounding box to force a concentric layout around a selected node ( http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/cde4db55e581d10405f5/ ).

While you indicate you would like to avoid this solution it seems a straightforward solution. The implementation in the example is rather elegant.

Comment: I ended up implementing the bounding box, I'm going to tweak the box size accoring to the number of nodes. Maybe I will find a multiplier that will fits to my case. I will accept this a solution, since it seems that it is the only way to do that. Thanks!